Clip (mask) a Composable with drawn shape using BlendMode
I'm trying to make so that my content (Surface() with Text()) is clipped by circle and only what's inside the circle is visible. I'm using BlendMode.DstIn, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

If I use solid black color, then I get the result as if the mask has not been applied at all.

If I use semi-transparent color, then I get the result of content within circle being semi-transparent as well, but everything outside stays.


@Composable
fun BlendModeTest() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .circularReveal(radius = 80.dp),
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(300.dp),
            color = Color.Gray,
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.Center),
                text = "My content text",
            )
        }
    }
}

@Stable
private fun Modifier.circularReveal(
    radius: Dp,
): Modifier =
    this
        .graphicsLayer(
            compositingStrategy = CompositingStrategy.Offscreen,
        )
        .drawWithContent {
            drawContent()
            drawCircle(
                color = Color.Black,
                radius = radius.toPx(),
                blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn,
            )
        }

@Preview
@Composable
private fun Preview() {
    MaterialTheme {
        BlendModeTest()
    }
}


Result with clipping circle of opaque Color.Black

Result with clipping circle of semi-transparent Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f)


Why is the content outside of clipping circle ignored?
Documentation of BlendMode.DstIn says it should not be drawn.
